# Query a list of tables with last user update + number of rows

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me combining these 2 queries to have a single output with 3 columns: TableName, last_user_update and NumberOfRows? If you could add TotalSpaceMB as well, even better.

```
SELECT   object_name(Object_id) as TableName,
last_user_update
FROM        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE       database_id = DB_ID( 'databasename')
```

and

```
SELECT      T.name TableName,i.Rows NumberOfRows
FROM        sys.tables T
JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
WHERE       indid IN (0,1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  T.name TableName,
  i.Rows NumberOfRows, 
  last_user_update,
  (SUM(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS DataSpaceMB
FROM        sys.tables T
JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats us ON us.object_id = T.object_id
INNER JOIN  
sys.indexes IND ON t.OBJECT_ID = IND.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.partitions p ON IND.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND IND.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE indid IN (0,1)
AND database_id = DB_ID( 'databasename')
GROUP BY T.name, I.rows, us.last_user_update
```

Comment: Not sure why you editted the `OPTION` back into the code... :/

Comment: I just updated the DB name.... Please do your changes as you want...

Comment: Thank you, Kshitij! The first one worked, the second one didn't. How could I add TotalSpaceMB to it?

Comment: Please check it now @Juliana

Answer (score 0):

I think this works well.
Test this and take about the result.

```
SELECT      T.name TableName,i.Rows NumberOfRows, st.last_user_update
FROM        sys.tables T
JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
JOIN        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats st on st.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE       I.indid IN (0,1)
and st.database_id = DB_ID(DB_NAME())
```

Thank you.